# How to Write MySQL Select Statement to Show Latest Entry by Each UserID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which allows users to enter data.

The table has a UserID field, title, description and timeinserted (current timestamp).

Im trying to write an MySQL Select statement that will return the last row of data per UserID.

For example if I had 2 unique user IDs in a table, then two rows should be returned which have the latest time inserted timestamps.

Example table contents

```
+--------+------------+------------------+---------------------+
| UserID |   Title    |   Description    |    TimeInserted     |
+--------+------------+------------------+---------------------+
|      1 | Some title | Some Description | 2014-12-12 10:00:00 |
|      2 | More title | Desc             | 2014-11-11 12:12:00 |
|      2 | Some title | Some Description | 2013-12-12 10:00:00 |
|      2 | More title | Desc             | 2014-09-10 12:12:00 |
|      1 | Some title | Some Description | 2014-12-12 10:00:00 |
|      2 | More title | Desc             | 2013-11-11 13:12:00 |
|      1 | Some title | Some Description | 2014-12-12 08:00:00 |
|      2 | More title | Desc             | 2014-08-11 11:12:00 |
+--------+------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the latest entry by using a simple group by

```
select userid, max(TimeInserted) from content group by userid
```

use the result from the group by in the WHERE Clause like this:

```
select * 
   from content 
where (userid, TimeInserted) in

(
  select userid, max(TimeInserted) from content group by userid  
)
```

Comment: This just returns the UserID and the latest TimeInserted in the tbale. If I add title and description to this statement, it doesn't return the latest information.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it and one of the way is to use `left join`

```
select t1.* from `Field` t1
left join `Field` t2 on t1.UserID = t2.UserID
and t1.TimeInserted < t2.TimeInserted
where t2.UserID is null
```

Check the doc here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me although a little longer than I would have hoped.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.userid, 
                t1.title, 
                t1.description, 
                t1.timeinserted 
FROM   posts t1 
       JOIN (SELECT userid             AS id, 
                    Max(timeinserted)  AS max_time 
             FROM   posts 
             GROUP  BY id) t2 
         ON t1.userid = t2.id 
            AND t1.timeinserted = t2.max_time;
```